# Rounded corners on global view

Tags: ios7

What would be the best way to put rounded corners on entire iOS app? I know how to do it on individual views using setCornerRadius. Can I apply this to a global view or something? 
Thanks :)

[image: rounded corners]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean round the corners on the whole interface: Mask the window or root view with a rounded-corner mask.

If you mean automatically round all corners of all views: No, there's no magic formula. Just keep doing what you're doing. You could make a generic rounded-corner view and subclass that, but that won't encompass views that are not subclasses of it, obviously.

Comment: Let me know if I have not understood the question!

Comment: Thanks! I wanted entire app to have rounded corners (not subviews) :) All I needed to do was: [[_window layer] setCornerRadius:10.0f]; and [[_window layer] setMasksToBounds:YES]; in my app delegate :)